# Is it possible to access a history of your clipboard in Ubuntu?

Tags: clipboard

Every time I copy and paste something I save it to my clipboard. Is it possible to access a record of what I have copied and pasted on Ubuntu?

Comment: I guess this extension might help you...https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/779/clipboard-indicator/

Comment: I use Lubuntu, which includes `qlipper` by default (a *lightweigtht cross-platform clipboard history applet*)

Answer (score 7):

It needs to be installed any Clipboard Manager tool to save clipboard history.
You may install **CopyQ Clipboard Manager**  from Ubuntu software center or by running following command in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install copyq
```

CopyQ is an advanced clipboard manager with editing and scripting features. It is an open source software available for free for major Linux distributions. It monitors system clipboard and saves its content in customized tabs. It can save both text and images from the clipboard. Saved clipboard can be later copied and pasted directly into any application.
CopyQ sits in the system tray and you can easily access it from there. By default, it shows only five recent clips. You can open the main window using “Show / Hide main window” option in the system tray. CopyQ can save up to 200 clips. You can also edit clipboard items here.

Answer (score 2):

You can install a clipboard manager to keep and manage entries that were previously copied to the clipboard. One such tool, developed for the Gnome Desktop, is gpaste. It also includes a Gnome Shell extension for tight integration in the Ubuntu desktop. You can install this Gnome Shell extension using Ubuntu Software, or Synaptic Package manager, or with the command

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extensions-gpaste
```

This will set up both `gpaste` and the gnome-shell extension. After installation, you will need to turn it on using Gnome Tweaks or the "Extensions" tool (Ubuntu 20.10 and up).

Alternatively, there is a stand-alone Gnome Shell extension, [gnome-shell-extension-clipboard-indicator](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/779/clipboard-indicator/). That extension is not officially supported by the Ubuntu developpers, but can be installed from the Gnome Shell extensions website.

Other clipboard managers are also available in the Ubuntu software center, including CopyQ, Parcellite and  Diodon, among others.